# Matlab: get the number of lines of a part of a text file

Tags: matlab

This is part of the data:

```
 GLOBAL DOF SET =
      1     3     4     5     6    33    35    36    37    38
     65    67    68    69    70    97    99   100   101   102
    129   131   132   133   134   161   163   164   165   166

 GLOBAL DOF SET NODES, LABELS =
        1 UX            1 UZ            2 UX            2 UZ            3 UX  
        3 UZ            4 UX            4 UZ            5 UX            5 UZ  
        6 UX            6 UZ            7 UX            7 UZ            8 UX  
        8 UZ            9 UX            9 UZ           10 UX           10 UZ  
       11 UX           11 UZ           12 UX           12 UZ           13 UX  
       13 UZ     

 MASS INFORMATION:
  TOTAL MASS =  12197.    
  CENTROID (X,Y,Z) =  30.000      0.0000      8.5809    
  MOMENT OF INTERTIA ABOUT ORIGIN:
    IXX = 0.10651E+07    IYY = 0.18383E+08    IZZ = 0.17318E+08
    IXY =  0.0000        IYZ =  0.0000        IZX =-0.31397E+07
```

How can I get the number of lines of the `GLOBAL DOF SET NODES, LABELS =` Part?

In this case, the number is `6`.

I think it maybe something to locate the `GLOBAL DOF SET NODES, LABELS =`line(using strfind?)  and the end empty line. But how?

Comment: you can use MATLAB `regexp`. Try this - `regexp(your_line, '\S(GLOBAL.DOF.SET.NODES.LABELS.*)*');` if there is no match, keep incrementing a counter from 1 onwards. Stop as soon as you hit a match i.e. a non-empty matrix, then get you get your line number.

Comment: Your last paragraph does indeed outline the right way to do this.  Where are you stuck?  Opening the file?  Getting the content as a cell array of lines?  Calling `strfind`?

Comment: @BenVoigt, I don't know how to code `the last line is empty line` and `the first line is xxx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you can use strcmp or strfind or regexp, comparing strings. The key is to get a string to compare. This is done by reading the file line by line using the **fgetl** function.

```
# Open your file and assign it's handel to fileID:
fileID = fopen('yourFile.txt','r');    

# Let's use the strcmp method and define your strings you test with:
yourFirstLine = ' GLOBAL DOF SET NODES, LABELS =';

# Your second line, in this case and empty line:
yourSecondLine = '';

# Use the variable flag to signal that you found your first line:
flag = 0;
iLine = 0;

 while ~feof(fileID)

     currentLine = fgetl(fileID);

     # Check if header line matches with the current line and store in iMatchOne:
     if strcmp(currentLine,yourFirstLine)
         iMatchOne = iLine;
         flag = 1;
     end

     # If you already found your first line it's time to start testing for the second line.
     if flag == 1
        if strcmp(currentLine,yourSecondLine)
            iMatchTwo = iLine;
            # You could decide here to break, because more matches with '' will be found!
        end
     end
     iLine = iLine + 1;
 end
```

Hope this helps!

Non essential:
( you could also add an if flag == 0 to the first check . Another way to go would be to break the while loop once you found your first line, and resume in a new while loop and perform the test for your second line, note that the liner number fgetl retrieves is not reset until you either close/reopen or manually reset the current line location. )

Comment: Where is `iLine` coming from?  Are you assuming it is a variable that starts at zero and is incremented inside the loop?

Comment: Cheers, sloppy, Fixed!